# Microsoft Edge does not start -- side-by-side error cannot resolve reference 84.0.522.48

Tags: windows-10

This morning after a reboot (I think after an update) Microsoft Edge no longer stars. Starting on command line gives the following error:

```
c:\Temp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

I found one suggestion to install some msvcrt version but that did not help.

If I run `sxtrace Trace` and then `sxtrace Parse` I see a message that Activation failed

```
 =================
  2 Begin Activation Context Generation.
  3 Input Parameter:
  4         Flags = 0
  5         ProcessorArchitecture = AMD64
  6         CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
  7         ManifestPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
  8         AssemblyDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\
  9         Application Config File =
 10 -----------------
 11 INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe.
 12         INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
 13         INFO: Reference: Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="&#x2a;",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win    32",version="6.0.0.0"
 14         INFO: Reference: 84.0.522.48,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="84.0.522.48"
 15 INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="&#x2a;",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="wi    n32",version="6.0.0.0".
 16         INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture AMD64.
 17                 INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
 18                         INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
 19                                 INFO: No publisher policy found.
 20                                 INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
 21                         INFO: Begin assembly probing.
 22                                 INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
 23                                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en-US_6595b6414    4ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
 24                                 INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
 25                         INFO: End assembly probing.
 26                 INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
 27                         INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
 28                                 INFO: No publisher policy found.
 29                                 INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
 30                         INFO: Begin assembly probing.
31                                 INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
 32                                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en_6595b64144cc    f1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
 33                                 INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
 34                         INFO: End assembly probing.
 35                 INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
 36                         INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
 37                                 INFO: Auto Servicing Policy redirected assembly version.
 38                                 INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,processorArchitecture="AMD64",publicKeyToken="    6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.18362.959".
 39                         INFO: Begin assembly probing.
 40                                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df    _6.0.18362.959_none_e6c7bbbf130c62bb.manifest.
 41                                 INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.18362.    959_none_e6c7bbbf130c62bb.manifest.
 42                         INFO: End assembly probing.
 43 INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="AMD64",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type=    "win32",version="6.0.18362.959".
 44         INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture AMD64.
 45                 INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
 46                         INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
 47                                 INFO: No publisher policy found.
 48                                 INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
 49                         INFO: Begin assembly probing.
 50                                 INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
 51                                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.18362.959_en-US    _6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
 52                                 INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
 53                         INFO: End assembly probing.
 54                 INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
 55                         INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
56                                 INFO: No publisher policy found.
 57                                 INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
 58                         INFO: Begin assembly probing.
 59                                 INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
 60                                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.18362.959_en_65    95b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
 61                                 INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
 62                         INFO: End assembly probing.
 63 INFO: Resolving reference 84.0.522.48,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="84.0.522.48".
 64         INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture 84.0.522.48,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="84.0.522.48".
 65                 INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
 66                         INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
 67                                 INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
 68                         INFO: Begin assembly probing.
 69                                 INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
 70                                 INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
 71                         INFO: End assembly probing.
 72                 INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
 73                         INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
 74                                 INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
 75                         INFO: Begin assembly probing.
 76                                 INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
 77                                 INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
 78                         INFO: End assembly probing.
 79                 INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
 80                         INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
 81                                 INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
 82                         INFO: Begin assembly probing.
 83                                 INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
 84                                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\84.0.522.48.DLL.
 85                                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\84.0.522.48.MANIFEST.
 86                                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\84.0.522.48\84.0.522.48.DLL.
 87                                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\84.0.522.48\84.0.522.48.MANIFEST.
 88                                 INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
 89                         INFO: End assembly probing.
 90         ERROR: Cannot resolve reference 84.0.522.48,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="84.0.522.48".
 91 ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
 92 End Activation Context Generation.
```

Comment: Have you tried DISM and SFC? https://www.techbout.com/repair-windows-system-files-using-sfc-dism-12162/

Comment: Installing latest version on top fixed the problem

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - DISM and SFC does not work for non-system files like Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author is unable to reproduce the problem after reinstalling Microsoft Edge

Comment: @MiserableVariable You have a typo twice in your answer: it's `sxstrace`, not `sxtrace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by reinstalling MS Edge